# Robust distance comparing predicate

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I need a robust predicate defined by the following code:

```
CompareResult compareDistance(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d) {
    if (distance(a, b) > distance(c, d))
        return Larger;
    else if (distance(a, b) == distance(c, d))
        return Equal;
    else
        return Smaller;
}
```

Due to the floating point arithmetic limitations we can't compute `distance` exactly (even its square), so if we just directly implement this code, the predicate will not be robust. I tried to find it in CGAL library, but couldn't.

Somewhat close to the predicate I need is `compare_distance_to_point(Point p, Point q, Point r)` [predicate](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Kernel_23_ref/Function_compare_distance_to_point.html). It returns `Smaller` if `distance(p, q) < distance(p, r)`, `Equal` if `distance(p, q) == distance(p, r)` and `Larger` otherwise. The first thought is to shift `c` and `d` by `(c - a)` vector, so we could call `compare_distance_to_point(a, b, d + (c - a))`, but this will violate robustness again. So, does anyone have an idea for adapting it?

Comment: Check "Robust Adaptive Floating-Point Geometric Predicates" article at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a kernel with exact predicates such as
[Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Kernel_23_ref/Class_Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.html),
you can use the functor Compare_distance_3 which is a model of the concept [CompareDistance_3](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Kernel_23_ref/FunctionObjectConcept_Kernel--CompareDistance_3.html).

`Kernel::Compare_distance_3 cmp;`

return cmp(a,b,c,d);